# Can i use another template engine with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can i use another template engine with Angular? i googled it and most of it just refer to the current template engine used by angular, i need a template engine with simple logic like "if", "or" .. thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular doesn't have a template engine replacement, mostly because there isn't a template engine like in other frameworks (ie. Backbone.js).  In Angular, there is string interpolation (`{{expression}}`) but no templates.

I'd first point you to the ngIf directive, where you can conditionally include DOM elements:

```
<div ng-if="somethingIsTrue">TRUE</div>
<div ng-if="!somethingIsTrue">FALSE</div>
```

If that's not enough, consider your template engine of choice to pre-process your HTML.  You can set up a grunt task to turn template files into HTML files that Angular can then reference.

Answer (score 4):

Brian mentioned `ng-if`, `ng-switch` could possibly also serve your needs:

```
<div ng-switch on="selection">
    <div ng-switch-when="settings">Settings Div</div>
    <span ng-switch-when="home">Home Span</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>default</span>
</div>
```

This will switch on the value of `selection` with the values specified in `ng-switch-when` and use `ng-switch-default` as the default case.

[Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably rewrite $interpolateProvider, but don't recommend to do so